# First call to fgets in SplFileObject doesn't advance file key

Tags: php, iterator, spl, splfileobject

Consider following text file, `test.txt`:

```
1
2
3
```

And following PHP code:

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject('test.txt', 'r');
var_dump($file->key());
$line = $file->fgets();
var_dump($file->key());
$line = $file->fgets();
var_dump($file->key());
$line = $file->fgets();
var_dump($file->key());
$line = $file->fgets();
var_dump($file->key());
```

It outputs:

```
int(0) int(0) int(1) int(2) int(3)
```

As you can see, key is equally 0 before and after first call to `fgets()`. Why? Is it intended? Is it a bug?

The behavior is identical setting `SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD` flag.

I'm using `PHP 5.3.10-2`

Thank you!

**Edit**

Looking at [`SplFileObject` source code](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc?revision=296679&view=markup), it think this is a bug.

[Method `key()`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc?revision=296679&view=markup#l293) just returns line number:

```
293 /**
294 * @return line number
295 * @note fgetc() will increase the line number when reaing a new line char.
296 * This has the effect key() called on a read a new line will already
297 * return the increased line number.
298 * @note Line counting works as long as you only read the file and do not
299 * use fseek().
300 */
301 function key()
302 {
303   return $this->lnum;
304 }
```

Which is stored in [`lnum` instance variable](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc?revision=296679&view=markup#l26), which is initialized to zero:

```
26   private $lnum = 0;
```

When [creating a new instance](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc?revision=296679&view=markup), it seems nothing happens to `lnum`, so after creating it still should have a 0 value:

```
32  /**
33  * Constructs a new file object
34  *
35  * @param $file_name The name of the stream to open
36  * @param $open_mode The file open mode
37  * @param $use_include_path Whether to search in include paths
38  * @param $context A stream context
39  * @throw RuntimeException If file cannot be opened (e.g. insufficient
40  * access rights).
41  */
42  function __construct($file_name, $open_mode = 'r', $use_include_path = false,    $context = NULL)
43  {
44    $this->fp = fopen($file_name, $open_mode, $use_include_path, $context);
45    if (!$this->fp)
46    {
47      throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open file $file_name");
48    }
49    $this->fname = $file_name;
50  }
```

Then, [calls to `fgets`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc?revision=296679&view=markupl60) should increase by one `lnum` ALWAYS, included first time, and this is not what it is happening:

```
60  /** increase current line number
61  * @return next line from stream
62  */
63  function fgets()
64  {
65    $this->freeLine();
66    $this->lnum++;
67    $buf = fgets($this->fp, $this->max_len);
68  
69    return $buf;
70  }
```

[`freeline`method](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc?revision=296679&view=markup#l331) just is setting another variable to NULL.

**Edit 2**

I reported a bug to PHP team: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61523

Comment: You should post the code snippets from source code where fgets calls `$this->lnum++`. I suspect the problem may be deeper rooted, but your observation appears valid.